# Why is it important that the combination of charge, parity & time reversal symmetry not violated?

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, cpt-symmetry, cpt-violation

If looking for more particles or decays that violate CP symmetry can explain why there is so few antimatter in the known universe, I guess finding things that violate [CPT symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry) might helps clear up some mystery about the universe. However all physics textbook insist that cpt symmetry must be conserved, why so?

Comment: I think CPT invariance follows from Lorentz invariance, so a violation would mean special relativity breaks down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to read carefully [this link](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/cpt.html). As a summary:

1)  CPT invariance is an experimental observation, that means  all data fitted by the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) have CPT invariance. Thus at the moment it is a law, i.e.axiomatic, as much as for classical gravitation Newtons law is observational and axiomatic.

2) It has been shown that if CPT is violated Lorenz invariance is violated, and there are no experimental observation supporting this, and innumerable measurements that validate Lorenz invariance.

> Georg Ludens, Wolfgang Pauli and Julian Schwinger independently showed that invariance under Lorentz transformations implies CPT invariance.

Comment: Exactly what value is Lorentz invariant in this argument?

Comment: All mathematical models of elementary particles are based, among other things, on Lorenz invariance. If there is no Lorenz invariance the models would have been falsified, or at least there would have been an experimental evidence that lorenz invariance is falsified, i.e. data inconsisten with Lorenz transformations, like decays of particles  and energy momentum changes between frames.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment only repeats your answer without specifying what value is Lorentz invariant. I understand the Standard Model is based on Lorentz transformations, but you are saying, "*Lorentz invariance*", not "Lorentz transformation". Invariance of what exactly? Of what value, vector, etc.?

Comment: lorenz invariant are th masses of the particles, for example, and all ivariant masses o complex systems too.

Comment: for vectors and matrices one speaks of lorenz covariance, i.e. consistency with lorenz transformations  see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: So CPT holds, because invariant mass is invariant?

Comment: @safesphere  It is a consequence of the validity of Lonrez transformations, i.e. that all data we have in particle physics up to now obey Lorenz transformations. The whole mathematical formalism of the standard model is built with Lorenz transformation invariance and covariance at its core. The model needs CPT invariance if valid.A violation would need a different model, , or a drastic modification, where Lorenz transformations would be violated..

Answer (score 0):

All Lorentz invariant theories are CPT invariant. Hence if you violate CPT invariance, you violate Lorentz invariance, and that's a big no-no.

Comment: @anna v *It has been shown that if CPT is violated Lorenz invariance
is violated*. AFAIK CPT theorem also requires local commutativity.
Recently Novikov showed a (non-local) model with Lorentz invariance
and CPT violation. And also a reverse situation: Lorentz violation yet
CPT invariance.

Comment: *All Lorentz invariant theories are CPT invariant.*
See my comment to anna v.

Comment: @ElioFabri  just saw this. You should have commented below the quote  you are giving. "non locality " is not an attribute of the standard model. IF cpt violation is found experimentally, this would be a candidate for an extension/modification of the standard model. It is data that demands the need to form a  verifiable theory after all.

Comment: @safesphere Sorry, I'd missed that warning.

Comment: @annav Motivation of my comment was to clarify relationship between
Lorentz invariance and CPT. In several posts the need for local
(actually, *weakly local* is enough) commutativity was not stated. I
said nothing about standard model or experimental evidence. My only interest was for logical implications. Now I've read a controversy
between Greenberg on one side, Novikov et al. on the other, and can't say my ideas are crystal clear. But connection between Lorentz and CPT should be qualified, IMHO.

Comment: @ElioFabri  my answer is in the framework of the standard model of particle physics and this is certainly a local qft. I do not know whether string theories are considered non local as they are not point lnteractions, so if the standard model is dressed with a string theory then certainly locality and non locality should be examined for the statements.